# I want to install vtigercrm 7.0.1 with Wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver, vtigercrm

** pre requisite for vtiger 7.0.1 is **

Apache 2.1+

MySQL 5.1+ (default storage engine = InnoDB)

PHP 5.2+, 5.3

Can someone tell me which version wampserver
 I have installed lastest wampserver of version 3.1.0 but after deploying the 
 vtigercrm its throwing below php exception

```
( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of Users::saveentity() should be compatible with CRMEntity::saveentity($module, $fileid = '') in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13
14  0.0987  7026040 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\Webservices\Utils.php' )    ...\CustomView.php:13

( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of Users::uploadAndSaveFile() should be compatible with CRMEntity::uploadAndSaveFile($id, $module, $file_details, $attachmentType = 'Attachment') in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13
14  0.0987  7026040 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\Webservices\Utils.php' )    ...\CustomView.php:13

( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of Users::insertIntoEntityTable() should be compatible with CRMEntity::insertIntoEntityTable($table_name, $module, $fileid = '') in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13
14  0.0987  7026040 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\Webservices\Utils.php' )    ...\CustomView.php:13

( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of Users::save() should be compatible with CRMEntity::save($module_name, $fileid = '') in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13
14  0.0987  7026040 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\Webservices\Utils.php' )    ...\CustomView.php:13

( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of Users::get_column_value() should be compatible with CRMEntity::get_column_value($columnname, $fldvalue, $fieldname, $uitype, $datatype = '') in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13
14  0.0987  7026040 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\Webservices\Utils.php' )    ...\CustomView.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 18
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 19
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 21
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 22
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 23
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 24
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 25
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 26
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
3   0.0193  589584  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\ModuleBasic.php' ) ...\Module.php:12
4   0.0221  633360  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Access.php' )  ...\ModuleBasic.php:10
5   0.0271  1138160 include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\UserInfoUtil.php' )   ...\Access.php:10
6   0.0592  3859376 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\utils.php' )  ...\UserInfoUtil.php:14
7   0.0612  3872680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ComboUtil.php' )    ...\utils.php:23
8   0.0637  3981680 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\utils\CommonUtils.php' )    ...\ComboUtil.php:11
9   0.0756  4885576 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator.php' )    ...\CommonUtils.php:26
10  0.0813  5737536 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\data\CRMEntity.php' )   ...\QueryGenerator.php:12
11  0.0880  5862304 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\RelatedListView.php' )  ...\CRMEntity.php:29
12  0.0905  5924848 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\ListView\ListViewSession.php' ) ...\RelatedListView.php:15
13  0.0951  6678976 require_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php' )    ...\ListViewSession.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 27
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0032  235944  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0110  301152  include_once( 'E:\Task\UC\wamp64\wamp\www\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\Module.php' )  ...\index.php:16
```

I think this is because of PHP version but not sure as I have no knowledge about PHP.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running? And what versions of Apache/PHP/MYSQL??

Answer (score 0):

You can define the error reporting level in your php.ini. It will not fix the errors in vTiger code, but it does hide those error messages.

```
display_errors = off
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: And restarted the web server? You are getting those error messages as the error_reporting level is set to show them. Please double-check the setting also from the vTiger configuration.